# How to separate IF statement from the whole string

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex

I am using c#. I have the query like below. Here I want to replace the equivalent query instead of IF condition query. For this I have to separate IF condition statement from the whole string. ( Ex: IF(DATEPART(\"MM\",TODAY())=1,12,DATEPART(\"MM\",TODAY())-1))

Can anyone suggest me how I achieve this?

" CASE WHEN (DATEPART(\"MM\",[Date])= **IF(DATEPART(\"MM\",TODAY())=1,12,DATEPART(\"MM\",TODAY())-1)** AND DATEPART(\"YYYY\",[Date])=**IF(IF(DATEPART(\"MM\",TODAY())=1,12,DATEPART(\"MM\",TODAY())-1)=12,DATEPART(\"YYYY\",TODAY())-1,DATEPART(\"YYYY\",TODAY())))** THEN (Date) ELSE (null) END "

Comment: If you using `c#` then do this formating/calculation on the client side in the c# code. Leave sql queries for database related tasks (saving, updating and  retrieving data). In `c#` this task will be easy to do in understandable, readable and maintainable way.

Comment: SQL Server does not have `if` like that, and the parameters to datepart are not strings. That definitely is not working code.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I wrote small example in Sql Server for you. Please verify-

```
 DECLARE @tbl TABLE ([Date] DATETIME)

 INSERT INTO @tbl ([Date])
 SELECT '2017-12-01'
 UNION
 SELECT '2018-01-12'

 SELECT
 CASE
    WHEN (
        DATEPART(MONTH,[Date]) = DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
        AND DATEPART(YEAR,[Date]) = DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
        )
    THEN [Date]
    ELSE NULL
 END
 FROM @tbl
```